# R - ddply extract value by one of two factors

Tags: r, plyr

I have this kind of data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), b=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3))
```

and I want to create a column depending of `a` and `b` but also a column depending only of `a`.

I tried to use `ddply`

```
df1 <- ddply(df, c("a", "b"), summarise, c=a+b, d=length(a))
```

but `length(a)` returns only ones as there is only one element per vector (`a` and `b` combinations).

If I do

```
df1 <- ddply(df, c("a", "b"), summarise, c=length(df$a))
```

I get the whole `a` vector (length=6).

I would like to access `a` depending of only one of the two variables I use in `ddply`. Is it possible? Should I not use `summarise` for that?

**EDIT**

I may have oversimplified this example. I need to group by two factors to compute the sum for each combination of these two factors and also the length of the vector according to the first factor. Here a new example:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 b=c(1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3),
                 val=c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   a b val
1  1 1   0
2  1 3   1
3  1 3   1
4  1 1   1
5  1 2   0
6  1 3   0
7  2 3   1
8  2 2   0
9  2 3   0
10 2 1   0
11 2 2   1
12 2 3   1
13 2 2   1
14 2 3   1

> ddply(df, c("a", "b"), summarise, sum=sum(val))

  a b sum
1 1 1   1
2 1 2   0
3 1 3   2
4 2 1   0
5 2 2   2
6 2 3   3
```

So I computed the sum of `val` for each combination of factors `a` and `b` and I would like to divide each element of the new vector `sum` by the length of `a==1` or `a==2`. So the results would be

```
  a b sum wanted
1 1 1   1 0.1666667 (1/6)
2 1 2   0 0.0000000 (0/6)
3 1 3   2 0.3333333 (2/6)
4 2 1   0 0.0000000 (0/8)
5 2 2   2 0.25      (2/8)
6 2 3   3 0.375     (3/8)
```

When `a==1` I divide by 6 and when `a==2` by 8 because there is 6 observations in `df` when `a==1` and 8 when `a==2`.

Comment: i think it's because of your grouping/split arguments, you would need to regroup based on `a` solely to get the behavior you desire

Comment: For the `a+b` you don't need a group by, i think you need `ddply(transform(df, c=a+b), .(a), mutate, d = length(a))`

Comment: @akrunThank you for your comments. I think I oversimplified the example because in my real case I need to group by two factors and then by the first only. See my update!